# how to check the content of text box is pure java code or not in angular

Tags: angularjs

I have a text area in Angular which takes java code as value. I want to check rather user is typing error free java code or not? Is there any library that could check its initial code error for java. so that I could show the user errors while writing the java code in Text area in angular application. thanks

Answer (score 0):

try

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ctrl/ngx-codemirror

there's also a version for angularjs